# MIgration Error in Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

i was using sqlite 3 database previously,but when i switched to mysql,i am getting the following error.All my database is migrated

```html
i am  getting following error whenever i am running rake db:load

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails: DROP TABLE `advance_salaries` CASCADE
/home/vh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `_query'
/home/vh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `block in query'
/home/vh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/vh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `query'
```

Comment: can you post your migrations? is it the first time you are running load?

Comment: yes we are runing it first time